# Como converter para decimal campo do XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

Ao fazer a leitura de um XML de NFe eu faço a leitura de campos que em meu sistema são decimais, por exmplo qCom (Quantidade), vUnCom (Valor Unitário) e vProd (Valor Produto), mas o arquivo XML usa o ponto como separador de decimais, então ao fazer uma conversão simples o valor fica completamente errado, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que no arquivo está 80.0000 e convertendo fica 800000, achei algumas opções na internet, porem não funcionaram, como forçar a CultureInfo informando a pontuação, mas não me parece ser isso, tentei usar Decimal.Parse() etc... estou sem ideia do que possa ser, alguém com já passou por isso?

Comment: ps não faz um `replace` do ponto por vírgula?

Comment: Porque eu não sei qual seria o comportamento caso o valor seja por exemplo 6.342,33, se eu receber no XML 6342.33 ai seria possível, eu não testei esta possibilidade.

Comment: não acredito que a NF seja tão "sem padrão" assim, de cada hora vir um formato. Na documentação não fala o formato padrão que são enviados os dados?

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta?

Comment: Sim, segui a ideia de conversão mesmo e fazendo replace. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Como consta na [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number), ao receber uma string, pode-se convertê-la para os diversos tipos numéricos com os métodos `Parse` ou `TryParse` A diferença entre os dois métodos é a facilidade de não ser preciso se preocupar com exceções ao utilizar o `TryParse`.

No seu caso específico poderia ser usado o [Decimal.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1), mais especificamente o overload `TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Decimal)`. Por se tratar de um `TryParse`, há sempre o retorno `booleano` que indica se foi possível converter a `string` passada de acordo com os parâmetros informados. Neste overload pode-se passar

- a `string` que será convertida (parâmetro `s`),
- um `System.Globalization.NumberStyles` (parâmetro `style`), onde se pode definir estilos de formatação do número (no seu caso, poderia utilizar o `Number` ou `Float`, por exemplo),
- um `IFormatProvider` (parâmetro `provider`), onde os detalhes de representação do seu número podem ser especificados,
- um `decimal`, que conterá o número, caso a conversão seja possível (parâmetro `out result`).

O `provider` (um `IFormatProvider`) pode ser tanto um `CultureInfo`, podendo usar `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` ou especificar `en-US`, de acordo com o exemplo apresentado, ou um `NumberFormatInfo`, onde é possível detalhar o formato da `string` de entrada (ex: `#,##0.000`).

Um exemplo funcional do apresentado pode ser encontrado em https://dotnetfiddle.net/kAo4v2.